# Возможно ли произвести отладку приложения с включенными In App-ми

Tags: android

Делаю в первый раз приложение в котором есть встроенные покупки, так вот все настроил по статье [пруф на habr](https://habrahabr.ru/post/313416/), отправил в бетку с релизной подписью, продукты добавил и они активны, тестеров во все списки добавил. Начал делать дальше:

### Presenter

```
@Override
public void payment() {
    if (inAppBillingService != null && isBillingAvailable.get() && repo().isRemoteOperationAvailable()) {
        InAppProduct product = view().getPrices().get(0).getGenericProduct();
        try {
            Bundle buyIntentBundle = inAppBillingService.getBuyIntent(API_VERSION, context().getPackageName(), product.getProductId(), product.getType(), UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = buyIntentBundle.getParcelable(BUY_INTENT);
            view().startPayment(pendingIntent.getIntentSender());
        } catch (RemoteException | IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); // На всякий случай - это для тестов ;) 
        }
    }
}
```

### View - Fragment

```
@Override
public void startPayment(IntentSender sender) throws IntentSender.SendIntentException {
    startIntentSenderForResult(sender, REQUEST_CODE_BUY, new Intent(), 0, 0, 0, null);
}
```

Код отрабатывает, и появляется ошибка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
В onActivityResult возвращает код BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_ITEM_UNAVAILABLE == 4.

Если загрузить приложение из маркета тогда оплата отрабатывает!!!

Теперь главный вопрос - кто-нибудь знает возможно ли дебажить приложение с in App-ами? потому-что выкладывать и ждать 2 часа что бы посмотреть результат - это ад :(

PS.

- Все подписывается релизным ключем в Gradle(инфа 100%)
- Email-ы тестеров добавлены для бетки и теста оплаты
- versionCode и versionName совпадают
- Прилага опубликована
- Версия API - 3
- SKU - верные(Проверено over дофига раз)
- В манифесте разрешение есть и интерфейс aidl добавлен в проект

Comment: А юзер, под коим тестируете перешёл по ссылке из консоли и нажал "участвовать в бета-тесте"?

Comment: Да, аккаунт гугловкий

Comment: Я не уверен, что вы меня поняли. Аккаунт не может не быть гугловым. Вопрос в том, заходили ли вы с этого акка по ссылке из консоли и соглашались ли на тестирование?

Comment: По ссылке тестер перешел и согласился

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему, может кому поможет. Значит так, на устройстве обязательно должен быть только один Google аккаунт, если больше, тогда будет ошибка типа этой. ¯_(ツ)_/¯ Вот так и живем.